# Can I change an external script's HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this [worldnomads partner quote form](https://www.worldnomads.com/Partner/GetPartnerWidget) in some posts with a script tag, however this external form uses an H1 title which messes up my heading hierarchy. I was wondering if it is possible to edit this?

Comment: Probably not; XSS (Cross Site Scripting) is a security issue so most external scripts don't allow it.  Have you reached out to World Nomads?